# All fields data not submitting to zendesk ticket form via php api

Tags: php, zendesk-api

I have integrated my website from with zendesk, I am following [this](https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_api_client_php) api library, I am successfully creating tickets to zendesk but, The problem is I am not able to send all the form fields to zendesk ticket form. Only subject and description field data is sending through my code.

This is my web form
[image: This is my web form]

This is my zendesk ticket form
[image]

This is my zendesk ticket listing
[image]

This is My code to create ticket

```
 public function CreateTicketOnZendesk($subject,$email,$description,$transactionNumber){
    try{
        $client = $this->zendesk();
             $newTicket = $client->tickets()->create([
                 'subject'  => $subject,
                 'comment'  => [
                     'body' => $description
                 ],
                 'custom_fields'=>[
                     'email'  => $email,
                     'transaction_number'  => $transactionNumber,
                 ],
                 'priority' => 'normal'
             ]);
             return true;
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        error_log($e->getMessage());
    }
 }
```

But cannot send the email and transaction number field data tried adding these field like sending subject as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom fields should be passed as `id`,`value` pairs try using this for `custom_fields`. To get fields id you can go to ticket fields panel on zendesk or can use this api `api/v2/ticket_fields.json`

```
 'custom_fields'=>[
                     [
                         'id'=> '<email_field_id>', 
                         'value'=> $email
                     ],
                     [
                         'id'=> '<transaction_number_field_id>',
                         'value'=> $transactionNumber
                     ]
 ],
```

Comment: did you use the field id, or the field name?  the ID can be found by clicking on the field in admin UI, or by loading api/v2/ticket_fields.json.  ID will also need to be int rather than string.  If still not working, can you share the response header and body, and also the exact payload sent to Zendesk?

Comment: @JimmyLong what if I have to create a ticket on specific ticket form?

Comment: @OwaisAslam you should only need to add the 'ticket_form_id' parameter to the payload when creating the ticket.

Comment: @JimmyLong is there any way to add attachments to ticket form?

Comment: Did you check this part of the README? https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_api_client_php#attachments